# Viewing the actual Timeseries data of FinancialData Object

Tags: time-series

How can i get a list of all the entries in `FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}]` ? I would like to read the actual entries but examples i am seeing has been plotting the data. How can print out the TimeSeries data for the object. Is there a command which will print the properties of an object also?

Comment: try `ts = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}]; Normal @ts` or use
`ts["DatePath"]` (See [TimeSeries >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) for the properties you can extract.)

Comment: use `percentchange` instead of `percent_change`. ([Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) has a very special meaning/role in Mathematica.)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the property `"FractionalChange"` as the second argument to `FinancialData` to get a time series of percent changes:

```
fractionalChange = FinancialData["SP500", 
  "FractionalChange", 
  {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}]
```

[image]

The first 10 rows of `fractionalChange`:

```
Take[Normal @ fractionalChange, 10] // Column
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[fractionalChange]
```

[image]

Yet another way is to use built-in [`FinancialIndicator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialIndicator.html) [`"RateOfChange"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/indicator/RateOfChange.html) to get a time series object of percent changes:

```
ts = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10,   22}}];

rateOfChange = FinancialIndicator["RateOfChange", 2] @ ts
```

[image]

First 10 rows:

```
Take[Normal @ rateOfChange, 10] // Column
```

[image]

The two series `rateOfChange` and `fractionalChange` have the same path of `{time, value}` pairs if we take the `QuantityMagnitude` of values in `fractionalChange`:

```
rateOfChange["Path"] == 
  TimeSeriesMap[QuantityMagnitude, fractionalChange]["Path"]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

ts = FinancialData["SP500", {{2014, 10, 23}, {2016, 10, 22}}];

data = Normal[ts][[All, 2]];
```

Note that variable names cannot contain a [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) (`_`)

```
percentChange = 100 Differences[#]/Most[#] & @data;

DateListPlot[
 Transpose[{Rest[Normal[ts][[All, 1]]], percentChange}],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have 1 question, in `percentChange` there is a space between 100 and Differences. Why is there no * (multiplication sign there). Just trying to understand the syntax which is used in Mathematica

Comment: A space is an implied multiplication.